# Configuration to set favicon in a Mattermost website

Tags: favicon, mattermost

I would like to change favicon image on my Mattermost website (example image of a favicon http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-tip-adding-a-favicon-to-your-website/images/chrome.jpg) but I don't find a configuration in which I can set this parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in configuration, see [the feature request](https://mattermost.uservoice.com/forums/306457-general/suggestions/14183451-ability-to-customize-the-site-favicon) if you want to vote for it.

If you're hosting it outside of docker or building yourself you could just replace the files in `<webapp>/images/favicon` (that's where it is in the code it might be different in the built version).